# Heroku: reinitialize database for Phoenix

Tags: phoenix-framework, ecto

This is mainly for testing purposes, but how can I achieve the same effect as `mix ecto.reset` on Heroku. The command as such leads to `FATAL:  permission denied for database "template1"` at the `drop` stage. But I would like to drop all tables and reset all incremental counters, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I remember, Heroku don't let you 'drop' databases but do have built in commands that do let you reset the database.

If you have the CLI toolkit for heroku you should be able to run these commands:

> heroku pg:reset DATABASE_NAME

Then you can run

> heroku run mix ecto.migrate

This should reset all of your counters and everything else you were after.

For more info, have a look at this link [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#using-the-cli) on Heroku's website

Answer (score 6):

For the complete steps:

```
heroku pg:info // get db_name from add-on field. 
heroku pg:reset DB_NAME
heroku run MIX_ENV=prod mix ecto.migrate
heroku run MIX_ENV=prod mix run priv/repo/seeds.exs
```

And finally, you can restart the dynos with `heroku restart`

Answer (score 0):

`heroku run mix ecto.migrate` will only work if you are running Elixir directly on the dyno (e.g. with an Elixir buildpack). It won't work if you're running your Elixir app in a container (as I am).

`heroku pg:push` will copy a local database to your Heroku Postgres instance. You can accomplish resetting both your dev database and your Heroku database like so:

```
mix ecto.reset
heroku pg:reset DATABASE_URL
heroku pg:push my_app_dev DATABASE_URL -a my_app
```

Note:

- `heroku pg:push` expects an empty database, so you need to run `heroku pg:reset` beforehand. In the scenario described in the original question, this is the desired effect, but if you *don't* want to empty your database first, this won't (necessarily) work for you.
- There's a corresponding `heroku pg:pull` command to move the database in the opposite direction. If you need to make big changes to your database, can't afford to reset it completely, but *can* tolerate a little downtime, you may be able to pull the database from Heroku, make your changes, and push it back. Be certain you know what you're doing before trying this.

`heroku pg:push` and `heroku pg:pull` are documented at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#pg-push-and-pg-pull.